# Why is R's which function not returning "correct" answer

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a variant of the [**Monty Hall problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem), building up on another person's code. The difference is that instead of 3 doors, I have "n" doors. Let's say `n = 4` for this question. The doors are labeled `A, B, C and D`.

The code is as follows:

```
n <- 4
doors <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = n )]
xdata = c()
for(i in 1:10000) {
    prize <- sample(doors)[1]
    pick  <- sample(doors)[1]
    open1 <- doors[which(doors != pick & doors != prize)]
    open  <- sample(open1,n-2)

    # the line with the problem
    switchyes <- doors[which( doors != open & doors != pick)]

    if(pick==prize) {
        xdata <- c(xdata, "noswitchwin")
    }
    if(switchyes==prize) {
        xdata=c(xdata, "switchwin")
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the warning:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

**The problem** seems to be due to the line:

```
switchyes <- doors[which( doors != open & doors != pick)]
```

This should only return 1 item (`C`) since the statement `doors != open` and `doors != pick` eliminates doors `A` and `B` and `D`. However, I'm getting more than one, `B` and `C`. Anybody see what's going on?

```
length(which(xdata == "switchwin"))
# [1] 4728
length(which(xdata == "noswitchwin"))
# [1] 2424
switchyes
# [1] "B" "C"
open
# [1] "B" "D"
open1
# [1] "B" "D"
pick
# [1] "A"
prize
# [1] "C"
```

Comment: Also when you post code I'd recommend 2 things: (1) indent (2) don't make those that may help you remove the `+` and `>` signs that litter your code.

Comment: lovely, works great now, thank you very much

Comment: A general suggestion: when R code doesn't work as you expect, don't word your question as if it's necessarily R's fault. Although it's obviously possible for R to have errors in it, the chances that a problem in a basic R calculation is actually **R** doing something wrong, rather than it being an issue with what the user is doing is miniscule. It would be better to word it neutrally ("why isn't this giving the result I expect?" rather than "why is R wrong?"). When I make errors in R, I *always* assume the fault is mine in some way. It has always turned out to have been a correct assumption.

Comment: @blindjessie why don't you post that as an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is the usage of `!=` when LHS and RHS size differ:

```
p <- letters[1:4] 
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

q <- c("a", "e", "d", "d")
# [1] "a" "e" "d" "d"

p == q
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

p != q
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

What is happening? since `p` and `q` are of equal size, each element of `p` is compared to the value at the corresponding index of `q`. Now, what if we change `q` to this:

```
q <- c("b", "d")

p == q
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

What's happening here? Since the length of `q` (RHS) is *not equal to* `p` (LHS), `q` gets recycled to get to the length of `p`. That is,

```
# p    q  p    q
  a == b, b == d # first two comparisons
  c == b, d == d # recycled comparisons
```

Instead you should use

```
!(doors %in% open) & !(doors %in% pick).
```

Also, by noting that `!A AND !B = !(A OR B)`. So, you could rewrite this as

```
!(doors %in% open | doors %in% pick)
```

In turn, this could be simplified to use only one `%in%` as:

```
!(doors %in% c(open, pick))
```

Further, you could create a function using `Negate`, say `%nin%` (corresponding to `!(x %in% y`) and replace the `!` and `%in%` in the above statement as follows:

```
`%nin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
doors %nin% c(open, pick) # note the %nin% here
```

So basically your statement assigning to `switchyes` could read just:

```
# using %bin% after defining the function
switchyes <- doors[doors %nin% c(open, pick)]
```

You don't need to use `which` here as you are not looking for indices. You can directly use the logicals here to get the result. Hope this helps.